# Data is obtained in the error function of the ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I'm trying to fetch the data from the datatable using ajax in cakephp. I'm sending a data named designation and wanna fetch all the records against that. This is how I've tried:

```
ajax:
    $("#Designation").click(function(){
                alert($("#Designation").val());

                var data = {
                    "Designation": $("#Designation").val()
                }

                $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    url: '<?php echo Router::url(array('controller'=>'DynamicForm','action'=>'getbulkoptions')); ?>',
                    data:data,
                    success:function(data){
                        alert("success");
                        console.log(data);
                        if(data.fieldid=="0"){
                            //MyNotif.Show(data.message,"warning");
                            alert("Field Exists");
                        }else{
                            $("#mymodal").modal('hide');
                            //MyNotif.Show(data.message,"success"); 
                            //window.location.reload();
                            alert("Bulk List");
                        }
                    },
                    error:function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                        console.log(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                    }
               });
            });
```

This is how I try to communicate with the DB:

```
DynamicFormController:
<?php

namespace App\Controller;
session_start();
use App\Controller\AppController;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;


class DynamicFormController extends AppController {
public function getbulkoptions(){
        $optionvalue = $this->request->data('Designation');
        $designation = TableRegistry::get ('Field');

        $result = $designation->getbulkoptions($optionvalue);
        echo json_encode($result);
    }
}
    ?>

FieldTable:
<?php
namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Table;

use Cake\Datasource\ConnectionManager;

class FieldTable extends Table {
    var $name = 'FieldTable';
public function getbulkoptions($designation){
        $conn = ConnectionManager::get('default');
        $stmt = $conn->prepare( "CALL proc_getbulkoptionslist (:tid)");
        $stmt->bindValue( ':tid', $designation);
        $stmt->execute ();
        return $stmt->fetchAll ('obj');
    }
}
```

The thing is, I get a proper response. I get the data I want, but that data is being printed in the error function of the ajax. I want it to be in the success function. I don't know what's wrong with the above code. When I tried to print the error, I got this:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 364 of the JSON data
Stack trace:
n.parseJSON@http://localhost/payrollengine/js/jquery.js:4:16508
Wb@http://localhost/payrollengine/js/jquery.js:4:18828
y@http://localhost/payrollengine/js/jquery.js:4:22274
.send/c@http://localhost/payrollengine/js/jquery.js:4:26750
```

I tried this in the error function and tried printing it out, I got this response:

```
    error:function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                            console.log(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                        }
response:
        [{"fieldvalueid":"1","value":"Manager"},{"fieldvalueid":"2","value":"Project Manager"},{"fieldvalueid":"3","value":"Software Engineer"},{"fieldvalueid":"4","value":"Senior Software Engineer"},{"fieldvalueid":"5","value":"Associate Software Engineer"},{"fieldvalueid":"28","value":"sample"},{"fieldvalueid":"29","value":"azhagu"},{"fieldvalueid":"37","value":"t"}]null
```

I don't know what's wrong with the code. Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: Try to add die; after echo json_encode() in your php code @SaiKrishna

Comment: is your json response valid ?

Comment: @parthmahida I think the prob will be in the receiving part, ie in the success function. I guess.. I tried using die, but no reaction.

Comment: what is with the null value at the end of the json array?

Comment: @madalinivascu: Even I don't know why it showing null. Searching for that only.

Comment: Try dataType: 'json', not JSON @Sai Krishna

Comment: @parthmahida Your answer die() was right. I used it wrongly. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: will you please upvote the comment @SaiKrishna

Answer (score 0):

Add the json header to your controller function:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($result);
```

try to return a associative array from the db

```
->fetchAll('assoc');
```

Comment: Same bro, no reaction

Comment: Yes. What might be that null, at the end of the responese??

Comment: @SaiKrishna you are returning something else besides the json object from your controller, try to add die after the echo as parth sad

Comment: I tried using `die` like this. `echo json_encode($result);
  die("Unable to connect");`  Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: die without a message

Comment: Thanks Bro, Got it. But, that's not the solution. The solution is adding this line `$this->autoRender = false;` in the controller whereever we use the ajax, since I'm using cakephp. This does the work. Using `die()` is also a solution. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @SaiKrishna sorry i am not familiar with cakephp

Comment: No problem. Anyway you gave me an answer. Thanks a lot for that.

Comment: The solution should be to do it the CakePHP way, and use either a serialized view, or to properly configure and return the `$this->response` object! @SaiKrishna